# Custom UIView to detect user touches

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch

I'm developing an iOS 4.0 application.

I want to add a custom `UIView` over an image (`UIImageView`) to detect when user touches on some image's parts. I don't want to subclass `UIImageView` because I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) package (or maybe I can subclass `UIImageView+WebCache` class to handle touches. If you tell me how).

This `UIImageView` will be inside an `UIScrollView`.

My idea is to detect when a user touches the image and notify `viewController` where user has touched. I don't need to detect moves or swipes or multitouches. Only one finger touch.

I'm creating my own `UIView` subclass to detect that using methods `touchesBegan`: `touchesEnd`:, etc. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do that.

What do you think? Do you know a better approach?

Comment: I've found a tutorial about this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-detecting-touches/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tapGestureRecognizer to your imageView in viewDidLoad, and then in handler method use `CGPoint gestureLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.imageView];` to check that tap was in selected area.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget to say that `UIImageView` is inside a `UIScrollView`. I don't know if I can use your answer this an `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`. Thanks.